# Function execution took 60002 ms, finished with status: 'timeout' for callable function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am experiencing an issue with Firebase callable functions and Auth triggers. You can see the callable function below. When it works it usually takes less than 1 second to finish but it started give frequent timeout errors since yesterday. Same thing for the Auth trigger, I was simply returning a Promise that writes user email to the Firestore in that case.

```
exports.respondToInvite = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

    if (!context.auth) {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('failed-precondition', 'The function must be called ' +
            'while authenticated.');
    }

    const uid = context.auth.token.uid;

    const inviteId = data.inviteId;
    const groupId = data.groupId;
    const accepted: boolean = data.accepted;

    try {

        const batch = admin.firestore().batch();
        const inviteRef = admin.firestore().collection("invites").doc(inviteId);
        batch.update(inviteRef, {
            userId: uid,
            status: accepted ? "accepted" : "rejected",
        })

        if (accepted) {
            const groupUsersRef = admin.firestore().collection("groups").doc(groupId).collection("users").doc(context.auth.uid);

            batch.set(groupUsersRef, {
                createdAt: admin.firestore.Timestamp.now()
            })

            const userRef = admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(uid);

            batch.set(userRef, {
                "groupId": groupId
            });
        }

        await batch.commit();

        return "invitation accepted";

    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('failed-precondition', 'invite response failed',error);
    }
});
```

Edit:
Here is the Auth trigger function

```
exports.newUser = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
    const userRef = admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(user.uid);
    return userRef.create({
        "email": user.email,
    });
});
```

Comment: Where is deployed your function, in which region?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere us-central1

Comment: Yesterday there were network issues in us-west2. Not sure that cause your problem.

Comment: I was testing it couple of minutes ago and again I got a timeout.

Comment: If you are querying much data try to [extend](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#functions-concepts-after-timeout-nodejs) your timeout. Also [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/writing-and-viewing-logs?) you can find more logging ways for your function.